# PHP Bar Locator Zipcode MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I keep on getting empty screen with no attributes in XML file when using this on my php file

```
  // Get parameters from URL
  $center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["Lattitude"] ) ? $_GET["Lattitude"] : 37 ); 
  $center_lng = ( isset( $_GET["Longitude"] ) ? $_GET["Longitude"] : -122 );
```

[image: no distance]

But when i specifically define $center_lat and lng to a location then it will give me a distance in XML FILE.

```
 // Get parameters from URL
 $center_lat = '40.4861111';
 $center_lng = '-74.4522222'; 
 $radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] ) ? $_GET["radius"] : 25 );
```

[image: some distance]

Can anyone please tell me whats going on? Help appreciated

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What values are the variables set to in your first example (do test outputs), and what code do you use to fetch the data?

Comment: @Pekka웃 This is what i have in my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084236/find-a-nearest-bar-with-a-zip-code-google-maps-sql-php

Comment: OK, but that doesn't answer the questions above

Comment: @Pekka웃 What do u mean by variables set to in my first example. Thats why i don't know whether its suppose to automatically fetch the location from databse or we have to define it every time

Comment: What value is `center_lat` set to, what is `center_lng`? And how are you sending those variables to the service? Somewhere along the line, things go wrong and the process to find out *why* is debugging the code step by step. All programmers have to do that frequently, even the very best ones

Comment: I appreciate your help @Pekka웃 but i still don't understand would the user be entering the lat and lng and it will fetch by itself or we have to hardcore it in the php file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41493/discussion-between-user2501165-and-pekka-)

Answer (score 0):

The [**Ternary Operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) takes three operands - a condition, a result for true, and a result for false. The ternary operator is a shorthand way of doing if statements. In the example:

```
$center_lat = ( isset( $_GET["Lattitude"] ) ? $_GET["Lattitude"] : 37 );
```

First there is a condition `(isset( $_GET["Lattitude"] )`, then there is a question mark `?`, and then a true result, a colon `:`, and a false result. If `isset( $_GET["Lattitude"]` is true , `$center_lat` will be set to `$_GET["Lattitude"]`, otherwise it will be set to `37`. That one-liner ternary statement can be expressed in a normal if statement like this:

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_GET["Lattitude"] )  {
        $center_lat = $_GET["Lattitude"];//Value of $_GET["Lattitude
    } else {
        $center_lat = 37';//Default value
    }
?>
```

The problem with this is the default of 37 which is probably out of the range (40.4861111 in your example).

Also it appears you are not getting any value for `$_GET["Lattitude"]` otherwise it would be used rather than the default.

Comment: I assume you have an input in your calling program to choose radius.

Comment: Thanks David, could you please also mention why do we need $radius     = ( isset( $_GET["radius"] )); when getting parameters from URL. I tried it again with the information you gave and still gives me empty xml file